# In git my master is some commits ahead the development branch

Tags: git, github, merge, commit, pull-request

My master branch is 22 commits ahead of development though I always rebase my master from development when I make a release. When I now merge the master in development these commits are merged but no file has changed

In detail:

My workflow for releases is the same since month:

- create a feature branch from development branch
- making changes on feature branch
- pushing changes and make a pull request
- accepting pull request by merging feature branch into development
- go back into client and pull the changed development branch
- update master from development
- push master
- on github make release from the last master's commit

When I then looked in Git Desktop (or github) and compare master and development, it normally showed zero differnces, nothing ahead, nothing behind.

Now, as I wanted to push a new feature branch, I saw that there is a difference of 22 commits, mostly (but not all) merge commits with the automatically given title "Merge branch 'development'". The oldest one is more than a half year old.

When I now merge master into development branch, all 22 commits are merged but no file has changed.

Though I'm quite calm because of the fact that no file has changed, and I will work with this development branch along, I want to understand what happened here.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you do update your master exactly?  (In above scheme, by the way, `development` branch is redundant)

Comment: @0andriy: After I merge the feature branch in development, in Github Desktop I fetch development, go to master branch and make "Update from development". Last one is a command in Github Desktop under "Branch".

Comment: To be more precise with "I fetch development": I fetch *and* pull development.